# These two code snippets are similar but show different results

Tags: c++, linked-list

first code snippet

```
void insert_last(Node* head,int new_data)
{
    Node* new_node = new Node();
    new_node->data = new_data;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = new_node;
        return;
    }
    Node *cur = NULL;
    cur = head;

    while(cur->next!=NULL)
    {
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    cur->next = new_node;
}
```

and the second one :

```
void insert_last(Node** head,int new_data)
{
    Node* new_node = new Node();
    new_node->data = new_data;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    if(*head == NULL)
    {
        *head = new_node;
        return;
    }
    Node *cur = NULL;
    cur = *head;

    while(cur->next!=NULL)
    {
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    cur->next = new_node;
}
```

The class is called Node with two data members

1. data (type=int)
2. *next (type = Node)

What is the reason that these two code snippets show different results when they are called and which one to use ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm also fairy new to C++, but this is what I think.

Passing `Node** head` will pass a pointer to a pointer, ensuring that the head pointer is changed outside of the local scope as well.

Check out [passing pointers by reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/passing-reference-to-a-pointer-in-c/).

In the first code_snippit, I believe that you'd need to return the updated head pointer for the desired result, while the second snippit modifies the data outside of the local scope.

Comment: `Node**head` is a pointer to a pointer, `Node*&head2` is a reference to a pointer, so `Node**head` will pass a pointer to a pointer by value.

Answer (score 1):

`Node**head` is a pointer to a pointer, `Node*&head2` is a reference to a pointer, so `Node**head` will pass a pointer to a pointer by value.

In the first snippet you passed a pointer by value, changing this pointer inside the function will not change the pointer that was passed to the function.
In the second snippet you pass a pointer to a pointer by value.
Changing the dereferenced pointer to pointer (which you do) : `*head = new_node;` will effectively change the pointer to `Node` that is being pointed to.

In the first snippet `head = new_node;` you are changing the value of a pointer that was being passed by value, the change to this pointer is only local.
Had you passed this pointer by reference like this :

```
void insert_last(Node* &head,int new_data)
```

Then the two functions would behave the same